# Why doesn't this opamp circuit work?

Tags: operational-amplifier, inverting-amplifier

I did a standard inverting operational amplifier (UA741), with Rin = 6k and Rf = 1k.

[image: Text]

I have a lab power supply, with 30V of difference for the amplifier.

I don't understand why this doesn't work, it should be Vout = -Vin/6 but I measure Vin = Vout = V-(AO).

I put Vin between 0 and 10V for instance, static, and voltage measurements are made with a standard voltmeter. I tried with several new op amps and it's the same problem.

[image: Text]

Comment: What is Vee?  and AO(?)  Are you expecting a negative output voltage ?

Comment: Where is your power supply connected? Show the full schematic.

Comment: V-(AO) is the point between the two resistors

Comment: Is your GND halfway between your supply rails, i.e. are they +/-15V wrt GND?

Comment: Is that a 741 op amp? What is its pinout, and how does that compare with the photo of the circuit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an inverting amplifier hence with Vin at some positive value, Vout has to be a negative value but, you don't have a negative supply rail on pin 4 hence it won't work because the output cannot become a negative value.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just put a 30V power supply on the op-amp, you need a ground so that you have something like +/-15V.

If your lab supply does not share a ground with your signal source you can create a pseudo ground at DC by doing something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faZpig.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: V2 +/- will float up and down if V1 signal has a signal thru R2 current. So not quite OK.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Well, it's expected to float up and down, that's the whole premise. Simulation with a 10Hz 10V input: https://i.imgur.com/5LKx7my.png

Comment: ground impedance is too high relative to 1k.   http://tinyurl.com/yyayzlfe

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  You forgot a connection.

Comment: Some improvement http://tinyurl.com/yy5qn3ou